# Norm of linear functional with e

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to find norm of this functional:

$$\ell^{4/3} \ni (x_n)_1^{\infty} \rightarrow \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n x_n\right)_1^{\infty} \in \ell^{4/3}$$

I proved that this functional is continuous, since:

$$\left\|\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n x_n\right)\right \| \le e \cdot \| (x_n)\|$$

But I can't find norm of this functional. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ denote the natural basis of $\ell^{4/3}$, then
$$
\Vert f\Vert\geq \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{|f(e_n)|}{\Vert e_n\Vert}=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(1+n^{-1})^n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+n^{-1})^n=e
$$
so $\Vert f\Vert\geq e$, but as you already showed, $\Vert f\Vert\leq e$, therefore $\Vert f\Vert=e$

Comment: Is there any theorem that says that we need to check only basis vectors?

Comment: no, this is not enough

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: there are examples where maximum is not attained at basis vectors. For example $$f:\ell_1\to\ell_1:x\mapsto (x_1+x_2)/2$$

Comment: But why in this particular case checking $e_n$ was enough?

Comment: because it multiplies each cooordinate by coefficient. In fact $\Vert f\Vert=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|a_n|$ for any functional $$f:\ell_p\to\ell_p:(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mapsto (a_nx_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$

Comment: I get it, thanks!

Comment: But if $f:\ell_p\to\ell_p:(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mapsto (a_nx_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ then $\Vert f\Vert=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|a_n|$ is correct yes?

Comment: Hmm but it doesnt give us $e$ when used in the first post case